# Laravel running long tasks on server

Tags: php, laravel, cron, background-process

I'm using laravel 5 and i have about 2000 instagram account's. And i need to check their current followers/following status every day and save them in my database.

The cron job was a perfect choice because i can say at what time of the day i want to run it, and it worked fine when i had less number of accounts.

But now my cron job often closes after i have download data for around 600 usernames. I read somewhere on internet that cron jobs are good for short running tasks that needs to be scheduled at specific times.

My tasks will grow with number of account's and currently it needs around 2 or 3 hours to finish. What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: This is mostly a matter of optimizing your existing code and server hardware. With the hardware we cannot help you. But with the code, you would need to provide us with some main pieces of code in order for us to help you with your problem. Also, processing your database rows in batches is also a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Put some column such as 'in_process' check into your DB regarding Instagram account for which you are processing followers/status.

Run another job if one is killed. Now your job should process accounts which haven't been processed yet.

Comment: I will give it a try :)